# Py serial readline not working in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.6, raspberry-pi3, pyserial

I have the following code working in Python 2.7:

```
import serial, io
import pynmea2


ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 9600, timeout=1)
while True:
    reading = ser.readline()
    if reading.find('GGA') > 0:
        msg = pynmea2.parse(reading)
        print "Lat: %s " % (msg.lat)
```

But the same code here doesn't work in Python3:

```
import serial, io
import pynmea2


ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 9600, timeout=1)
while True:
    reading = ser.readline()
    if reading.find('GGA') > 0:
        msg = pynmea2.parse(reading)
        print("Lat: %s " % (msg.lat))
```

The error message is:

**if reading.find('GGA') > 0:
TypeError: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'**

How do I get the code working in Python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python 3 the string type was separated from the byte sequence. This means that `'GGA'` is a string literal, while `reading` is a sequence of bytes. There are several ways you can resolve it.
First. Convert `reading` to string by calling `reading = reading.decode()` (you need to know which encoding is there).
Second. Convert your literal to bytes either with `'GGA'.encode()`, or by creating bytes literal `b'GGA'`.

Comment: @user3141181 If this answers your question please mark it as a solution.